# Execute a lisp function in the future ONE time

Tags: function, common-lisp, scheduler, sbcl

I have an API post route that takes in some information from the user.

The API is built with Common Lisp. When the form is submitted, I would like to "wait" for 24 hours to execute a function.

So, a sort of scheduler for execution.

I looked at `cl-cron`, but I only want this to execute one time at a variable date that i can specify manually.

How can I create this for a long running lisp image?

### What the code looks like now

```lisp
;; note - defroute is part of easy-routes library

(defroute post-route ("api/post/route" :method :post) (&post name email)

    (validation-function ...)
    (save-to-db ....) 
    (do-something ...) ;; < -- these 3 are implemented

    (schedule-future-action firstname email seconds-in-future) ;; <--- not implemented 


    (redirect ...) < -- implemented

)
```

Comment: Is something like (bt:make-thread (lambda () (sleep (* 24 60 60)) (do-delayed-action))) possible, or would it result in too many running threads? If the latter, you can make one "scheduler" thread, but I will wait if someone has an answer where it is already done and nicely packaged

Comment: Also, you can look to https://github.com/zellerin/http2/blob/master/server/scheduler.lisp for inspiration.

Comment: Yeah, I think opening a new thread would be an issue because I expects hundreds of post requests, if not thousands per daay.

Comment: I would have one thread dedicated to scheduling, with a channel receiving new tasks and a priority queue. BUT, first the scheduler would journal everything on the filesystem because you cannot rely on your process being alive so long. Then, if you shutdown and restart the server, it would pick up where it left and continue scheduling.

Comment: Yes, this this is a great point. Can you point me in the general direction of how a file system based queue would work? More specifically, how to implement a queue system in general would help. Thanks

Comment: Maybe SBCL timers? Implemented with system calls on top of `setitimer`, does not require a scheduler thread http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Timers (I didn't use them).

Comment: Maybe checkout: https://github.com/npatrick04/timer-wheel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a solution based on coredump's comment.

I built a priority queue data structure that keeps a record of events. The queue is saved on the local file system. It is sorted by the time stamp of the event (which depends on user action).

When the controller activates, actions get saved and sorted into the queue.

Finally, a second thread, runs cl-cron. Which runs a function every 1 minute. It reads the first item in the priority queue, if ready executes and delete item. if not do nothing.

The important part is, as coredump suggested, if the lisp image crashes for whatever reason, the cron job can continue where it left off.